# Save file with a generated name from vim command mode

Tags: vim

I am trying to save file with a generated name from vim command mode. I am using the command:

```
:w !tee"/tmp/vim/$(date +'%s').tmp"
```

But it throws me an error that filename cannot be empty. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
:w !tee "/tmp/`date +'\%s'`.tmp"
```

Explanations:

- '%' is expanded by vim into the filename, this is why it complains about it being empty. You need to escape it.
- The bash style `$(...)` commands seem not to work in vim system calls.